# Error while using "micv" smooth function in predict.gam (mgcv)

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

While predicting for the GAM model with `mgcv` package, built using `micv` smooth function(from `scam` package) for one of the co-variates, I get the following error:

```
Error in predict.gam(mod_gam, newdata = dfGAMDev) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Code:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(car)
 library(mgcv)
 library(scam)

mod_gam <- gam(Y ~  X1 +  X2+   X3+  s(X4, bs='micv') +  X5,  data = dfGAMDev )
predDevGAM <- predict(mod_gam, newdata =dfGAMDev)
```

I tried the following as well:

```
predDevGAM <- predict.gam(mod_gam, newdata =dfGAMDev)
```

all the variables are numeric

Comment: Could you show us code and data?

Comment: Are these packages designed to work together?

Comment: @Maju116, I have added the code and all the variables are numeric.

Comment: @Pascal, I am not sure. I will research on that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to build a shape constrained GAM model, with unconstrained GAM model function, `gam` instead of `scam` function. The following code worked:

```
 mod_gam <- scam(Y ~  X1 +  X2+   X3+  s(X4, bs='micv') +  X5,  data = dfGAMDev)
```

Apologies for raising the issue. I misunderstood, that the smooth functions in the scam package can be used in gam function